# Is it ever necessary to define a method as "public"?

Tags: php, oop, public-method

If all methods are public unless they are explicitly defined as something else, is it ever necessary to define a method as `public`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you answered the question already by naming the default: no, it is not necessary.

[To quote the manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Class methods ***may*** be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

However, I consider it good practise to always do so.

Answer (score 1):

Because `public` [is the default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Visibility_of_properties_and_methods) it isn't necessary to define it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two style tendencies in php - the "javaesque" majority considers visibility modifiers very important and uses them actively, in the pythonesque minority (i personally belong to) we think that all that public-private-interface-abstract stuff is nothing more but a waste of RAM.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear why!

Comment: @stereofrog: Neither of your responses answer sunwukung's question; they're actually rather cargo cult in nature. "If python doesn't use it, it must not be worthwhile" isn't an answer.

Comment: @stereofrog: Neither of those come close to answering sunwukung's question. Asking a question with a desired answer, and deliberately stating that you're going to ignore people who disagree with you isn't valuable at all. Like sunwukung, I would be fascinated to read about why the python community considers access modifiers unnecessary, but neither of your answers have come close to providing that information.